# Where does cross-validation fit into a model selection workflow with inference?

Tags: regression, cross-validation, p-value, hyperparameter, decision-theory

Say we have some model, $f(x) = \hat{Y}$, such as linear regression, that estimates an output dependent value for some set of input data.

We want to do inference on the coefficients of the model to estimate features' influence on the dependent variable.

We also want to properly evaluate the predictive accuracy of the model.

Would a suitable work flow go as follows:

- Model feature selection using measures such as AIC, BIC etc.. and regularization
- Inference on coefficients
- Finally, k-fold cross-validation to estimate predictive accuracy (such as MSE).

It seems to me we need to not do *any* cross-validation or parameter tuning until inference is complete. Otherwise, our p values will not be valid. Our predictive assessment must be made independently of our model selection.

Does this make sense?

Comment: How do you plan to do things like regularization without hyperparameter tuning?

Comment: Feature selection very seldom works even under ideal conditions (large N, no collinearities, high signal:noise ratios).  In other conditions it's a disaster.  What makes you think feature selection works in your case?  When I say _works_ I mean that it has a remote chance of finding the right features.  See https://www.fharrell.com/talk/stratos19/.  Contrast feature selection with ridge regression and data reduction (unsupervised learning to restrict the number of variables used to predict the outcome).